# VBA create new Worksheet if not exists

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a VBA macro, that takes data from a Worksheet and copies it to another.
If the destination Worksheet does not exist it should create it and than write the data from my array.

**Problem:**
I have a function to test if the worksheet already exists.
If it is the case my macro will successfully write the data i want. But if the worksheet doesnt exist VBA is displaying the error you can see below.
In the list Workbook.Worksheets is no Sheet named like this but I get that error anyway.

**Here is my relevant code:**
(If something is missing for understanding the problem I can fill in the missing part in too)

```
Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Sheet
    sheetExists = False
End Function
```

In my main Sub I used this code:

```
If sheetExists("SheetName") = False Then
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        .Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "SheetName"
    End With
End If
```

**The exact error:**

> 1004 Cannot rename a sheet to the same name as another sheet, a reference object library, or a workbook referenced by Visual Basic

First it was executing successfully but after I deleted the sheet manually the error occurred.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: use `For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`

Comment: You can also substitute `If sheetExists("SheetName") = False` with `If Not sheetExists("Sheetname")`.

Comment: You could also use `On Error Resume Next`, try and set a reference to the worksheet `Set Sheet=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetToFind)` and then see if an error occurred - `sheetExists = (Err.Number = 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify in which workbook to look at:

```
For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
```

also not that **it has to be** `Sheets` and not `Worksheets`, because `Worksheets` only contains worksheets but `Sheets` also contains charts, etc. So we have to check these names too!
(`Sheet` then has to be `Dim Sheet As Object`)

You can make your function more flexible:

```
Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String, Optional InWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean
    If InWorkbook Is Nothing Then Set InWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

    Dim Sheet As Object
    For Each Sheet In InWorkbook.Sheets
        If sheetToFind = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Sheet
    sheetExists = False
End Function
```

so you can call it:

- `sheetExists("SheetName")` to use `ThisWorkbook` by default, or
- `sheetExists("SheetName", Workbooks("MyWorkbook"))` to specify a specific workbook.

---

Alternatively you can use

```
Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String, Optional InWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean
    If InWorkbook Is Nothing Then Set InWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

    On Error Resume Next  
    sheetExists = Not InWorkbook.Sheets(sheetToFind) Is Nothing
End Function
```

which can be a bit faster if there are many sheets in a workbook.

Comment: Hi PEH,
thanks for your quick help.
Your code works fine but I cant see the existing Worksheet "SheetName".
The function is returning true but I cant see any Worksheet called SheetName.
Is there a way to delete the Sheet completly before creating it?

By the way the Sheet iam creating is only used and created by my macro so no user will edit that. Thats why I only changed the Worksheets to Sheets in the function.

Comment: So I figured out to delete the Sheet with:

      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").Delete
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True

But I cant see the Sheet in my Workbook when I create it...

Comment: @PEH I tried scrolling but it didnt work. I even added the attribute Sheet.Visible = xlVisible to the create Sheet procedure but still nothing happens...
Do you or someone else got any more ideas?
Or should I open another question for that problem?

Comment: Probably a good idea to open up a new question and include a good description and a [mcve] that shows your issue.

Comment: Just to finish this. I was excecuting the macro from the personal workbook so everytime I called ThisWorkbook VBA used PERSONAL.XLSB and not the one I was working on... I have fixed it with an InputBox to select the correct Workbook.

Comment: @XxTSDTxX If you have this function in PERSONAL.XLSB you can just use `sheetExists("SheetName", ActiveWorkbook)` to run it on the workbook that has the focus (is on top) or better use `sheetExists("SheetName", ThisWorkbook)` to run it on the workbook this code line is in. Note that if you run `sheetExists("SheetName")` the function will run on the workbook where the **function** code is in.

Comment: @PEH thats what I did :) after the InputBox I called sheetExists with the workbook from the InputBox. I made a global variable to save the workbook from the user. This I used for all methods thats required a workbook. Thanks again for your help and have a nice weekend:)